# How can a Router talk to a View other than using a global variable?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events, backbone-routing

I can not understand why in my Backbone app (Todo app) after I reload a page (CTRL+F5) a `filterTodos` method does not get called. When I simply click on links to filter Todos ("Active", "Completed") - it does get called.

You can see this feature in links below. No matter how many times you click Refresh in Browser - correct filtered results are displayed:

http://todomvc.com/architecture-examples/backbone/#/completed

http://todomvc.com/architecture-examples/backbone/#/active

I have a theory that it's because I am triggering a `filter` event from `Router` too early - a `TodosView` is not initialized yet and therefore it does not **listenTo** `filter` event yet.

But how a `Router` can inform a `View` to re-render itself (based on filter) if this `View` does not exist yet? Can't it be achieved via triggering some event in `Router` as I do? One possible option is to have a global variable `app.FilterState`.

**Is there any other methods of communications between a Router and a non-constructed yet View?**

For `app.FilterState` I will set its state in `Router` and then check it in View and call `filterTodos` function manually like so and it will work:

**views/todos.js**

```
render: function() {
    app.Todos.each(function(todo) {
      this.renderTodo(todo);
    }, this);
    if (app.FilterState !== 'all') { // <--- ADDED CODE
      this.filterTodos(app.FilterState);
    }
    return this;
  }
```

Existing source code:

**routers/router.js**

```
var app = app || {};

var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    'all': 'all',
    'active': 'active',
    'completed': 'completed'
  },
  all: function() {
    console.log('all');
    app.Todos.trigger('filter', 'all');
  },
  active: function() {
    console.log('active');
    app.Todos.trigger('filter', 'active');
  },
  completed: function() {
    console.log('completed');
    app.Todos.trigger('filter', 'completed');
  }
});

app.Router = new Router();
Backbone.history.start();
```

**views/todos.js**

```
var app = app || {};

app.TodosView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#todo-list',

  initialize: function(todos) {
    console.log('initialize begin');
    app.Todos.reset(todos);
    this.listenTo(app.Todos, 'add', this.addOneTodo);
    this.listenTo(app.Todos, 'filter', this.filterTodos);
    this.render();
    console.log('initialize end');
  },
  render: function() {
    app.Todos.each(function(todo) {
      this.renderTodo(todo);
    }, this);
    return this;
  },
  renderTodo: function(todo) {
    var todoView = new app.TodoView({model: todo});
    this.$el.append(todoView.render().el);
  },
  addOneTodo: function(todo) {
    this.renderTodo(todo);
  },
  filterTodos: function(filterType) {
    console.log('filter'); // <--- CODE DOES NOT REACH THIS LINE WHEN CALLED ON BROWSER'S REFRESH (F5)
    var active = app.Todos.active();
    var completed = app.Todos.completed();

    if (filterType === 'active') {
      // hide remaining
      _.each(completed, function(todo) {
        todo.trigger('hide');
      });
      //show active
      _.each(active, function(todo) {
        todo.trigger('show');
      });
    }
    else if (filterType === 'completed') {
      _.each(completed, function(todo) {
        todo.trigger('show');
      });
      //show active
      _.each(active, function(todo) {
        todo.trigger('hide');
      });
    }
    else if (filterType === 'all') {
      app.Todos.each(function(todo) {
        todo.trigger('show');
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using Backbone Marionette? It comes with a built in pub sub communication system built in that makes it super easy to do this. Overall it gives you a great organization/modularization of your code by utilizing the pub sub system.

Comment: Also, it costs a little money but it's THE BEST Backbone/Marionette tutorial out there and comes with quite a bit of production ready code if you follow it all the way through - http://www.backbonerails.com/